# What is the pdf of the multiplication of two normal random variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, density-function

I want to know the pdf of the multiplication of two normal random variables (may or may not have the same mu and sigma, may or may not be correlated).

```
R> x=rnorm(100)
R> y=rnorm(100)
R> hist(x*y)
R> hist((x+1)*(y+2))
```

I tested for the above simplest cases. It seems that the resulted distribution has a long tail. Is there a parametric form of the distribution that can be used to best fit the multiplication of two normal random variables? For the fitting, up to 4th-order moment should be fine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I googled “product of random variables”, and the very first hit had an answer to this question. But beware that this, like any general answer, will involve Bessel and other non-elementary functions.

Comment: See answer hetr. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101062/is-the-product-of-two-gaussian-random-variables-also-a-gaussian

Comment: Are you assuming that they have a *joint* multivariate normal distribution? Or just that the marginals are normal?

Comment: The first......